# Nested Includes in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-includes

In Ruby on Rails I have School which has many children. Children which has many activities. And Activity which has one activity_types. I need help nesting includes. In my Children Controller. I have this... which works.

```
s = School.find(params[:school_id])
@school = s
@children = s.children.includes(:activities).all
```

But I want to also get the :activity_type from the activities from the children. I tried this

```
s = School.find(params[:school_id])
@school = s
@children = s.children.includes(:activities => :activity_types).all
```

But that did not work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't pluralize `activity_type`.

`s.children.includes(:activities => :activity_type).all`

Comment: Wow thank you. Why does that work? What is the logic behind that?

Comment: I'm assuming you made a typo when you wrote activity has one activity_types (plural) because you later wrote that you wanted to get the activity_type from an activity. `children.includes(:activities => :activity_type)` means include all activities for each children and include each activity_type for each activity. If you use the plural (activity_types) then that assumes that activities have many activity_types and not just one.